# How can I code away html and special characters in python?

Tags: python, regex

> 1543159687.4969957::I think I\u2019ve gotten far enough into my experiment to give an update: Last year, Child of Humanity was free
>   for Blac\u2026 https://t.co/M3HR5fAoFZ"

This is the result that I am getting. I'd like to create a regex to replace special elements like \u2019 and \u2026 with a space. They always start with "\u" and continue for four more characters.

I'd also like to get rid of the html. It always starts with "https://t.co/" and continues for 10 characters.

I've tried the code below but it is clearly wrong.

```
tweet = re.sub("@[\\u].{4}", "", tweet)
```

Comment: \u2019 is a unicode character, not an html thing.  For that matter, all of the characters in the string are unicode.  Perhaps you want to convert it to ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `\u` characters are simply unicode characters, there's nothing you need to do since they will be automatically converted when you try to `print mystring`

As to the final url, you can do:

```
removed = re.sub(r'http\S*$', '', mystring) # remove the final http string.

>>> removed
'1543159687.4969957::I think I’ve gotten far enough into my experiment to give an update: Last year, Child of Humanity was free for Blac… '
```

Comment: What if the string has two urls one right after the other? How can I tell the program to loop through and get the second one as well while keeping the code flexible for those strings that only have one url?

Comment: Twitter crawled only contain one, I have created a crawler to this effect before. But there’s also the pic.twitter.xxx link to watch out for.